# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')

Tags: reactjs

lib/sortNewsByImage.ts (2:29) @ data

1 | export default function sortNewsByImage(news: NewsResponse) {

> 2 | const newsWithImage = news.data.filter((item) => item.image !== null);
> |                           ^
> 3 | const newsWithoutImage = news.data.filer((item) => item.image === null);
> 4 |
> 5 | const sortedNewsResponse = {

Comment: try to give details about your question instead of just pasting the error you are getting

Comment: What's happening is the parameter you are passing into this function as news doesn't have an attribute named data.